Understanding ていた/ていなかった with もう/まだ
I have trouble understanding how [verb]+ていた works and how the meaning changes when it is paired with もう/まだ.
For example, what is the difference between

彼はアニメを見ていた。

and

彼はもうアニメを見ていた。

I think the former means at some point of time in the past, he started watching anime and this state continued to the time of observation by the speaker. However, it does not mean he suddenly stopped watching anime at the observation point. We don't know whether he is still watching anime or not now. The use of ていた emphasizes the fact that he was in the state of watching anime at the particular point in the past.
As for the latter, I believe it means at some point of time in the past, he started watching anime and this state continued to the time of observation by the speaker. The only difference with the former is that he actually stopped watching anime sometime around the observation point. We still don't know whether he is still watching anime or not now (?)
Is that correct?
I also want to know the difference between

彼はアニメを見ていなかった。

and

彼はまだアニメを見ていなかった。

I think there is not much difference between these two. まだ used in the latter emphasizes that he still haven't watched anime at some particular point of time in past.

-ている can both refer to a progressive action and the resultant state of a past action (perfective aspect). And もう cannot resolve this ambiguity:

彼はアニメを見ていた。

He was watching anime.
He had watched the anime (before).



彼はもうアニメを見ていた。

He was already watching anime.
He had already watched the anime (before).



彼はもうアニメを見ていなかった。

He was no longer watching the anime. (He was sleeping.)
He no longer watched anime. (He had quit the habit of watching anime at the point.)


The correct meaning depends on the previous context.
However, some other expressions can be used to determine the meaning of -ている in one way, without any further context:

彼は一度アニメを見ていた。

He had watched the anime once (before).



彼はアニメを見ているところだった。

He was watching anime.


まだ behaves differently depending on whether it's used in a negative sentence:

彼はまだアニメを見ていた。

He was still watching anime.



彼はまだアニメを見ていなかった。

He was not watching the anime yet (when I entered the room).
He had not watched the anime yet (although I told you to do so several weeks before).



Actually, I am struggling to see how adding もう/まだ affects the meaning of the sentence. I found a resource that explains in detail. The pictures are quite confusing and it led me to think that adding もう/まだ somehow slightly emphasizes the duration of the action or state...?

@JohnDavies Well, "妹は昼ご飯をもう食べていました" can also mean "My sister was eating lunch already" (past progressive), so もう by itself doesn't force the perfective reading, as described in my answer. But adding something like "11時の時点で (By 11:00)" will make the perfective reading much more likely, even without saying もう.
